# setup.bash bad call with catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros org,
I have experienced a bad issue with `catkin_make_isolated`. The file `devel_isolated/setup.bash` is not source by `.bashrc`.

For the background:
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, using ros kinetic. I had to reinstall Ubuntu few days ago (4 days but there was a weekend, so 2 days of use).
I uninstall and reinstall completely ros.
This is the content of the end of my bashrc file:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
#source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash
source ~/src/setup_px4.sh
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

As a result, source this file does not have any effect on my workspace. I can't launch any package

Therefore no problem from my package, sourcing myself the workspace is working well.

I just run the command, on the workspace root, `catkin_make_isolated`, and no compilation error.

Does anyone has a way to fix it? And also maybe underline what I might have done wrongly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352690/setup.bash-bad-call-with-catkin_make_isolated/) by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> This is the content of the end of my bashrc file:
>
> ```
> source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
> #source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
> source ~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash
> source ~/src/setup_px4.sh
> source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
> ```

these lines are executed in sequence, one after the other.

When you `source /path/to/setup.bash`, the last one wins (ie: overwrites all the others).

So with the sequence you show, first `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` is `source`d, then `~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash`, then `~/src/setup_px4.sh` and finally again `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`.

End result: as if only `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` was `source`d.

You'll typically want to `source /path/to/your/workspace/devel/setup.bash` *last*.

Or, alternatively, don't auto-`source` anything in your `.bashrc`, but manually `source ~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash` when you start a terminal.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on 2020-05-19**:
I just found it right after! I really didn't know it, thank you for the fast answer!

PS: I set my answer as deleted, as this one was set before mine